# Cannot find module 'semver/functions/cmp' React Native CLI

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, hadoop-yarn, react-native-cli

I have been developing the application in Expo. I've had to revert to using React Native CLI as I need access to a package Expo doesn't support. My project didn't run so I've built a new project by copying across all .js files and then yarn installing all the packages I need.

It's failing to build with the following error.
Can anyone help? I have no idea what's going on, I'm new to react native and the environment.

````
error: index.js: [BABEL] C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\index.js: Cannot find module 'semver/functions/cmp'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\core-js-compat\helpers.js
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\core-js-compat\get-modules-list-for-target-version.js
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3\core-js-compat\get-modules-list-for-target-version.js
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-runtime\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\metro-react-native-babel-preset\src\configs\main.js
- C:\Users\owenj\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\GlucoseProject\FYP\node_modules\metro-react-native-babel-preset\src\index.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Worker.js
- C:\Users\owenj\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js (While processing: "C:\\Users\\owenj\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FYP\\GlucoseProject\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro-react-native-babel-preset\\src\\index.js")```
````

Comment: Are you trying to build on an M1 chip by any chance?

Comment: I've since resolved thanks

Comment: would you mind posting your solution?